# Looking to implement a local data cache in an android app

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an in-house app that reads data from a WCF server.  It keeps a local copy of important items, but once it uploads successfully, it deletes the local copy.  This works great as long as there is cell coverage.  I have figured out that I need to keep a local copy of all recently accessed data so that the tablet isn't rendered useless if it loses cell coverage.  I was wondering if anyone had already written or thought through a system that would manage local data efficiently.  There are several important aspects I would like to see:

1. Whenever a record is read from the server, a local copy is created on "disk"
2. Also, when data is read from the server, it checks to see if the local copy has been successfully updated to the server before it overwrites the local copy.  If the local copy hasn't been updated on the server, it needs to use the local copy.
3. If it tried to update to the server and fails, then there needs to be a background process that tries to send it later when a cell signal becomes available.
4. It needs to be able to handle different record types and different key types for looking up the records.
5. It needs to be able to purge local copies of the records if they have not been accessed for a certain period of time.

Number 4 is my big sticking point.  Is there a good way to keep a collection of different types of records and different key types and numbers of keys in order to access them?

Comment: Probably could use Akavache: https://github.com/akavache/Akavache

Comment: Thanks, James.  I have downloaded Akavache and it seems like it is going to do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using Akavache [github.com/akavache/Akavache](http://github.com/akavache/Akavache) to implement my scenario.  It is a really cool set of libraries.  You can load it using NuGet.  Here is a link to a blog that has a basic demo of how to use it:
https://codemilltech.com/akavache-is-aka-awesome/.